# Access Violation while using _tcstok

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, utf-8, access-violation

I am trying to tokenize lines in a file using _tcstok. I am able to tokenize the line once, but when i try to tokenize it a second time, I get an access violation. I feel like it has something to do with not actually accessing the values, but locations instead. I'm not sure how else to do this though.

Thanks,

Dave

p.s.  I'm using TCHAR and _tcstok because the file is UTF-8.

This is the error I'm getting:

First-chance exception at 0x63e866b4 (msvcr90d.dll) in Testing.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000006c.

```
vector<TCHAR> TabDelimitedSource::getNext() {
// Returns the next document (a given cell) from the file(s)
TCHAR row[256]; // Return NULL if no more documents/rows
vector<TCHAR> document;

try{
    //Read each line in the file, corresponding to and individual document
    buff_reader->getline(row,10000);
    }
catch (ifstream::failure e){
        ; // Ignore and fall through
    }

if (_tcslen(row)>0){
    this->current_row += 1;
    vector<TCHAR> cells;
      //Separate the line on tabs (id 'tab' document title 'tab' document body)
     TCHAR *  pch;
     pch = _tcstok(row,"\t");
     while (pch != NULL){
         cells.push_back(*pch);
         pch = _tcstok(NULL, "\t");
     }

    // Split the cell into individual words using the lucene analyzer
    try{
      //Separate the body by spaces
        TCHAR original_document ;
        original_document = (cells[column_holding_doc]);
        try{
            TCHAR * pc;
            pc = _tcstok((char*)original_document," ");
             while (pch != NULL){
                 document.push_back(*pc);
                pc = _tcstok(NULL, "\t");
             }
```

Comment: Why are you casting to `char*` and not to `TCHAR*`? Also, you're treating a `TCHAR` like a `TCHAR*`, that's bound to be bad.

Comment: I got rid of some of the casting ect. Still same problem.

Comment: Blatantly not. Write it without casts, you should be able to find the error then.

Comment: Got rid of the char* cast and got this error: '_tcstok' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'TCHAR' to 'char *'
        Conversion from integral type to pointer type requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast. I don't understand why it would ask for a char* because I'm using TCHARs everywhere

Comment: David: Correct, that's the problem :-) You can't treat a char as a pointer. I think there's plenty wrong with your code, so I'm reluctant to advise, but something like `TCHAR * original_document = ...` should happen; but I think even your vector doesn't do what you want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First up, your code is a mongrel mixture of C string manipulation and C++ containers. This will just dig you into a hole. Ideally you should tokenize the line into `std::vector<std::wstring>`

Also, you're very confused about `TCHAR` and UTF-8. `TCHAR` is a character type that 'floats' between 8 and 16 bits depending on compile time flags. UTF-8 files use between one and four bytes to represent each character. So, you probably want to hold the text as `std::wstring` objects, but you're going to need to explicitly convert the UTF-8 into wstrings.

But, if you just want to get *anything* working, focus on your tokenization. You need to store the address of the start of each token (as a `TCHAR*`) but your vector is a vector of `TCHAR`s instead. When you try to use the token data, you're casting `TCHAR`s to `TCHAR*` pointers, with the unsurprising result of access violations. The AV address you give is `0x0000006c`, which is ASCII code for the character `l`.

```
  vector<TCHAR*> cells;
  ...
  cells.push_back(pch);
```

... and then...

```
    TCHAR *original_document = cells[column_holding_doc];
    TCHAR *pc = _tcstok(original_document," ");
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the first time I've needed to deal with UTF-8 files and it's kind of blowing my mind. It's way more complicated than I feel it should be.

Comment: Thank you so much. I understand that this really doesn't fix it, but it's great to see things going on so that I know everything else is working correctly. I'll definitely start to work on getting everything transferred to wstrings.